# Why is there no sign of facial hair in Pi's face?

Tags: character, life-of-pi

In Life of Pi, we can see the changes in Pi's physique like being slim, lengthening of his hair etc. But surprisingly he is clean shaved in that state too. How is that possible? In his age, as shown, he should have facial hairs i.e. moustache and beard. Is there any explanation for this?

Comment: Age and facial hair is a correlation, not causation

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Men typically start developing facial hair in the later years of
>   puberty or adolescence, between seventeen and twenty years of age, and
>   most do not finish developing a fully adult beard until their early
>   twenties or later. This varies, as boys may first develop facial
>   hair between fourteen and sixteen years of age, and boys as young as
>   eleven have been known to develop facial hair.(source : [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facial_hair))

Pi is only 16 years old during the course of the story, and not every 16 year old boy has facial hair.

Comment: I might add: some men can't have facial hair, even in their 20s. Natural.